# Alert User field that is blank is required

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

**Problem:** I would like to be able to alert the user if a particular field is empty. Here is how the form looks:

[image]

When the user enters a zip code and selects search, I would like a pop up to display to alert the user to select a distance and not display the results. If the user enters hospital name and city drop down, I do not want the alert to appear. Only when the zip code is entered and when the search button is selected.

Here is the form:

```
  <div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-body">
    <form name="UrgentCareSearch" ng-submit="SearchUrgentCare(searchParam);" novalidate role="form" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
        <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" id="hospital" ng-model="searchParam.HospitalName" placeholder="Hospital Name" type="text" /></div>

        <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" id="city" ng-model="searchParam.City">
        <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">City</option>  
        <option value=""></option>
                      <cfoutput query="HospCityFind">
                      <option value=#officecity#>#officecity#</option>
                    </cfoutput> 
                  </select></div>

        <hr />
        <div style="margin-top:-10px; margin-bottom:10px; text-align:center; font-size:8pt! important"><strong>* OR Search by Zip code radius *</strong></div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-7 no-right-padding">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <select class="form-control" id="miles" name="distance" ng-model="searchParam.Distance">
                        <option></option><option >5</option><option>10</option><option>15</option><option>20</option>
                    </select>
                    <div class="input-group-addon">miles</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-5 no-left-padding widthZip">
            <div class="form-group"><input allow-pattern="[\d\W]" class="form-control" id="zip" maxlength="5" ng-model="searchParam.Zip" placeholder="Zip code" type="text" /></div>
        </div>
    </div>

        <div class="form-group"><input class="btn btn-warning btn-block" ng-click="gotoElement('SearchResultsAnchor');" type="submit" value="Search" /></div>
    </form>
</div>
```

and here is the script that alerts when the miles is blank:

```
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["UrgentCareSearch"]["distance"].value;
    if (x == "" || x=="null") {
        alert("Please select distance");
        return false;
    }
```

**UPDATE**

I have done the following and it still does not work the way I want to (which is to show the alert when the search button is entered and when the user has entered a zip code. Meaning once the user has entered a zip code and click on the search button to populate the results, the alert will appear notifying to select the miles and the results will not show until user has entered how many miles and click search again):

```
function validateForm() {
        var x = document.forms["UrgentCareSearch"]["miles"].value;
        var $zip = $('#zip');
        if ((x == "" && $zip != "") ||(x=="null" && $zip != "")) {
            alert("Please select distance");
            return false;
        }
```

and this is what I when I used required:

```
  <div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-body">
    <form name="UrgentCareSearch" ng-submit="SearchUrgentCare(searchParam);" novalidate role="form" onsubmit="return checkTextField()">
        <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" id="hospital" ng-model="searchParam.HospitalName" placeholder="Hospital Name" type="text" /></div>

        <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" id="city" ng-model="searchParam.City">
        <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">City</option>  
        <option value=""></option>
                      <cfoutput query="HospCityFind">
                      <option value=#officecity#>#officecity#</option>
                    </cfoutput> 
                  </select></div>

        <hr />
        <div style="margin-top:-10px; margin-bottom:10px; text-align:center; font-size:8pt! important"><strong>* OR Search by Zip code radius *</strong></div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-7 no-right-padding">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <select class="form-control" id="miles" name="distance" ng-model="searchParam.Distance" ng-options="mile.value for mile in miles" required>
                         <option value=""></option><option >5</option><option>10</option><option>15</option><option>20</option>
                    </select>
                    <div class="input-group-addon">miles</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-5 no-left-padding widthZip">
            <div class="form-group"><input allow-pattern="[\d\W]" class="form-control" id="zip" maxlength="5" ng-model="searchParam.Zip" placeholder="Zip code" type="text" /></div>
        </div>
    </div>

        <div class="form-group"><input class="btn btn-warning btn-block" ng-click="gotoElement('SearchResultsAnchor');" type="submit" value="Search" /></div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Just add `required`

Comment: HTML5 form validation

Comment: Why the jQuery tag? I don't see any.

Comment: @j08691: You are correct. Thank You. Edited my question

Comment: @Wayne: required does not work on my end. Still shows the results

Answer (score 0):

adding `required` to each of the `input` or `select` elements would prevent the form from being submitted if they are left blank

```html
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-body">
    <form name="UrgentCareSearch" ng-submit="SearchUrgentCare(searchParam);" novalidate role="form" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
        <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" id="hospital" ng-model="searchParam.HospitalName" placeholder="Hospital Name" type="text" required /></div>

        <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" id="city" ng-model="searchParam.City" required>
        <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">City</option>  
        <option value=""></option>
                      <cfoutput query="HospCityFind">
                      <option value=#officecity#>#officecity#</option>
                    </cfoutput> 
                  </select></div>

        <hr />
        <div style="margin-top:-10px; margin-bottom:10px; text-align:center; font-size:8pt! important"><strong>* OR Search by Zip code radius *</strong></div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-7 no-right-padding">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <select class="form-control" id="miles" name="distance" ng-model="searchParam.Distance" required>
                        <option></option><option >5</option><option>10</option><option>15</option><option>20</option>
                    </select>
                    <div class="input-group-addon">miles</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-5 no-left-padding widthZip">
            <div class="form-group"><input allow-pattern="[\d\W]" class="form-control" id="zip" maxlength="5" ng-model="searchParam.Zip" placeholder="Zip code" type="text" /></div>
        </div>
    </div>

        <div class="form-group"><input class="btn btn-warning btn-block" ng-click="gotoElement('SearchResultsAnchor');" type="submit" value="Search" /></div>
    </form>
```

Or there can `jquery` touch look at this

first give your form an `id` lets say `myform`

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#myform').submit(function()
    {
        var name = $("#hospital").val();
        var name = $("#city").val();
        if(name == "" || name == " ")
        {
            alert("Please enter name");
            return false;
        }
        if(city == "" || city== " ")
        {
            alert("Please enter city");
            return false;
        }

        //Just like this and at the end when you are satisfied
        $(this).submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: There we go! I thought he can understand it easilu

Comment: Thank You. However, the alert still appears when I enter values for hospital Name and City fields. I would like it to only appear when the user only enters zip and then selects search

Comment: required does not work I add it to select field that contains the miles

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand by your problem statement, you can do the following in your validation function.

```
function validateForm() {
    var miles = document.forms["UrgentCareSearch"]["distance"].value;
    var zip = document.forms["UrgentCareSearch"]["zip"].value;
    if (zip && !miles) {
        event.preventDefault(); // This will prevent the form submit
        alert("Please enter the Miles.");
        return false; // Does't submit the form (for IE)
    }
}
```

Also, when calling the function, just call the function directly.

```
<form name="UrgentCareSearch" ng-submit="SearchUrgentCare(searchParam);" novalidate role="form" onsubmit="validateForm();">
```

Comment: @ Piysuh: I have tried your approach and it shows the alert only when the zip code is not empty and search button is clicked. However, when I close the alert message, it displays the results. How would i prevent the results to populate until the miles are selected and the search button is clicked again.

Comment: Hi @RobertoFlores, it works for me. Check out this https://jsfiddle.net/k99y7nu5/.

Comment: Hi @Piyush, It does work but as I mentioned, the results will populate rather then wait for the user to select the distance. So once the alert pop-up is closed, the results populate. I have tried required in the select mentioned here but it does not work and as far as I know, it is not supported in safari

Comment: I believe by 'release populate', you mean the form is submitted. Not sure why that happens in ur case bcoz returning false in the validate function should not submit the form (as happens in the fiddle I gave you).

Comment: Do you mean "results populate"? Also, I am not sure why it is populating the results. Do I have the onsubmit="return validateForm()" in the wrong spot?

Comment: How would I find the source of the problem using the inspector tool?

Comment: How would I force stop the results to populate until a mileage has been selected?

Comment: I just edited my answer, can you check it now. Also, to inspect the javascript  in general, use dev tools (F12 key on chrome) . Check the console for any wierd errors.

Comment: @ Piyush : tried your approach and yet it still shows the results. What you have changed is what I have already done in the code.Not sure what else i can do

Comment: You do do a hard refresh, right? (Ctrl + R on chrome).

Comment: @ Piyush: Yes I have and I removed the angular and refresh the page, even removed the cookies and everythign and still shows the same results

Comment: Will you be able to copy your exact code in fiddle or something? I can take a look if it still has a problem.

Comment: What you have done for the fiddle to show it was working, it works and is exactly what I did